# Replace unknown reference (?) with the tag from \ref or \cite

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

While working on a document, it would be helpful if instead of a `?` for unresolved references or citations the tag used in the `\ref{thisthings}` or `\cite{Bloke1978}` could appear instead.

Is there a package that turns on this behaviour?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than redefining `\cite` or connected commands, one might consider using the `showkeys` package, that will print *every* key and mark *every* usage of `\label` so that, during document preparation, cross-references can be checked quite easily.

This has a drawback: line and page break can be different when using or not using the package. However, line and page break are not much of a concern when we are writing our manuscript. When finalizing the project just comment out the call to `showkeys`: the cross-references should be OK, at that point.

Comment: That is a more useful solution than just replacing the unresolved labels.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, this is nice, but is almost useless for citation-heavy documents like reviews, because there is too much extra text.

Answer (score 14):

Even if there is no such package, it's easy to modify the corresponding commands with the help of the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. This may, however, fail if some package redefines the commands in an incompatible way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setref}{\bfseries ??}{[\texttt{#3}]}{}{%
  \GenericWarning{}{Failed to patch \protect\@setref}}
\patchcmd{\@citex}{\bfseries ?}{\texttt{\@citeb}}{}{%
  \GenericWarning{}{Failed to patch \protect\@citex}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{undefined},\pageref{undefined},\cite{undefined}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One might also consider the `showkeys` package.

Comment: @egreg: That's cool! Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: Adding to this MWE the package `\usepackage{natbib}` it does not work anymore. How has the `\patchcmd` for `citex` be modified?