# For missing references, how to get the citation key instead of a question mark?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace unknown reference (?) with the tag from \ref or \cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44939/replace-unknown-reference-with-the-tag-from-ref-or-cite)

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Please, use a minimal example (\cite{ref1}).
\end{document}
```

I compile it this way:

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

And, as expected, the resulting pdf is:

[image]

Is it possible, in such a case where I didn't provide any bibliography file, to have "[?]" replaced by "[ref1]"? Any simple hack would be very (very) useful ;)

Comment: Or even better: how to get missing citation keys or references highlighted in red?

Comment: Well, it's a duplicate of this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44939/3734